# Implementing the inheritance hierarchy in the State Pattern

Tags: java, c#, php, design-patterns, state-pattern

I have a design which is very similar to this:

[image]

Here **NewOrder**, **Registered** & **Granted** all have the common methods `AddOrderline()` and `Cancel()` , so refactoring both methods to a parent class is easy.

**The problem occurs when I want to `Cancel` a `Shipped` line (currently not shown in the figure).**

Since a **Shipped** line doesn't support `AddOrderline()` then I'll need to break the parent class for **NewOrder**, **Registered** & **Granted** into 2 class one for the `Cancel()` and another for `AddOrderline()`.

Now `NewOrder` must extend 2 parent class to get the 2 functions.

**Notes**

1. This example is very simplified. My real application has about 12 states.
2. The code is in PHP, but solutions in C# or Java are welcomed because I presume that the solution will be similar as they all don't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the separation of the interface from the implementation. e.g. in Java

```
interface Cancellable {
   void cancel();
}
interface Shippable{
   void ship();
}
```

etc.

```
public class NewState implements Cancellable, Shippable {
  public void cancel() { ... }
  public void ship() { ... }
}
```

If you have an underlying private State, it can implement *all* the required interfaces, and your public States need only delegate those supported states. e.g.

```
 public class UnderlyingState implements Cancellable, Shippable ... {
    public void cancel() { ... }
    public void ship() { ... }
 }

  public class ShippableState implements Shippable {
     private UnderlyingState ustate = new UnderlyingState();
     public void cancel() {
        // you can *only* cancel this
        ustate.cancel();    
     }
   }
```

In the above you'd probably need to return a new state object (rather than `void`) and have your `Order` adopt that new state. The `UnderlyingState` object would enforce some state machine.

The headache with this is that as your number of states increase, your interfaces and implementation increases too.

Comment: Apologies to whoever just upvoted this. I rewrote it completely.

Comment: I'm still not sure about this...should a state of an order really be the code that ships/cancels/etc the order? Think about dependency injection here...how will this state object access the database (which  I presume it would need to ship or cancel an order). In my opinion the job of the state is to determine what can or can't be done, but not _how_ to do it.

Comment: It can call *back* on the Order object to get the Order to perform certain actions. Alternatively if the Order implements each State interface (Shippable/Cancellable etc.) it can delegate to the state object to get the new state and then perform the related DAO actions itself. You're right in that the state shouldn't do the DAO stuff (you *may* want that State object for other entities - not just Orders)

Comment: @BrianAgnew Then why have the state action do anything other than return `true`/`false` if it's ultimately going to callback to the order to perform the action anyway?

Comment: @ColinMorelli - it could do, but I'd rather it returns the explicit state to move to, since that means the state machine is encapsulated completely

Comment: @BrianAgnew please check question again as I updated it to clarify the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, you'll need a state manager to handle states:

```
<?php
class StateManager
{
    protected $states = array();

    public function registerState(StateInterface $state)
    {
        $this->states[$state->getName()] = $state;
    }

    public function getState($state)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($state, $this->states)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        return $this->states[$state];
    }
}
```

Then you have an order manager that can perform actions against orders:

```
<?php
class OrderManager
{
    protected $stateManager;

    public function ship(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        try {
            $this->stateManager->getState($order->getState())->ship($order);
        } catch (OperationNotAllowedException $exception) {
            // However you want to handle the fact that the state can't be shipped
        }
    }
}
```

An exception that gets thrown if an order can't take an action in a certain state:

```
<?php
class OperationNotAllowedException extends Exception
{
}
```

The interface for a state:

```
<?php
interface StateInterface
{
    public function getName();

    // Then your normal functions
    public function ship(OrderInterface $order);
    public function cancel(OrderInterface $cancel);
    public function addOrderLine(OrderInterface $order);
    public function refund(OrderInterface $order);
}
```

Now, when you setup your application:

```
$newOrderState = new NewState($database, $otherdependencies);
$stateManager->registerState($newOrderState);
```

Your order object simply returns a string name for the state it's in, that matches what one of the state's `getName` methods returns.

This method also allows for easy mocking and testing (which is important for any application, but especially e-commerce where you are handling people's money and products).

Comment: please check question again as I updated it to clarify the problem.

Comment: I'd rather ask the Order itself if it can ship, rather than the state it contains. Demeter and all that...

Comment: @ColinMorelli what if I needed to change the way a `NewOrder` is `Cancelled` for example? the way I see it from your code that there can be only one implementation for it.

Comment: @Songo You could make the states perform the action _if it's necessary_. But if that's not something you'd do - I'd avoid optimizing for it. Most of the simple ways of doing that (the ones that you'd get in an answer on Stack Overflow since we obviously can't write your codebase for you) will do it incorrectly (not use proper dependency-injection and such) which will make maintenance a nightmare later.

Comment: @Songo Updated to support dependency injection in the states, and answer your previous question. There's now one object per state that gets re-used.

Comment: @ColinMorelli - I had the same!

Comment: @BrianAgnew The difference between yours and mine was that you used a state object which called back to an order object to perform actions. I'm trying to separate each piece of the system with my approach, using dependency-injected state objects across orders which are capable of performing actions on their own (rather than depending back on the order). Both are perfectly fine approaches.